# Need help writing a regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find a pattern in a string that has a value that starts with `${` and ends with `}`. There will be a word between the curly brackets, but I won't know what word it is.

This is what I have `\$\\{[a-zA-Z]\\}`

`${a}` works, but `${aa}` doesn't. It seems it's only looking for a single character.

I am unsure what I am doing wrong, or how to fix it and would appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close!

All you need is to use a `+` to tell the expression that there will be one or more of whatever was just before it (in this case `[a-zA-Z]`) like this:

```
\${[a-zA-Z]+}
```

Comment: @MaxZoom Because you are using a hyphen and a digit (number). The ranges specified are `a` through `z` and `A` through `Z`. There are no hyphens or numbers in those ranges. Digits can be added using `0-9`. A hyphen can be added escaped. The whole thing might look like this `[a-zA-Z0-9\-]`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this could help you

```js
var str = "The quick brown ${fox} jumps over the lazy ${dog}";

var re = /\$\{([a-z]+)\}/gi;

var match;

while (match = re.exec(str)) {
  console.log(match[1]);
}
```

Click <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> and check your developer console for output

```
"fox"
"dog"
```

**Explanation**

- `+` means match 1 or more of the previous term — in this example, match 1 or more of `[a-z]`
- the `(...)` parentheses will "capture" the match so you can actually do something with it — in my example, I'm just using `console.log` to output it
- the `i` modifier (at the end of the regexp) means perform a case-**i**nsensitive match
- the `g` modifier means match *all* instances of this regexp in the target string
- The `while` loop will continue running for each match that `re.exec` finds. Once `re.exec` cannot match another instance, it will return `null` and the loop will exit.

**Additional information**

Try `console.log(match)` using the code above. Each match comes with other useful information such as the string index where the match occurred

**Gotchas**

> This will not work for nested **${}** sets

For example, this regexp will **not** work on `"The quick brown ${fox jumps ${over}} the lazy ${dog}."`

Comment: This will not work with capitals. Along with that the user seems to only be asking for the regex instead of a JS program.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, I used the `i` modifier to perform a case-insensitive match. Also, I demonstrated usage with a javascript program to show that the `g` modifier was also probably necessary otherwise he'd probably only get one match. In this case, I think the simple program is helpful as it provides a complete demonstration of functionality. With your answer, he will likely hit another dead-end in a very short while.

Comment: How so? My answer is correct and gives exactly what was asked for, the question stated that only a word would be between `${...}`, the nested case you mentioned would never occur. You are assuming that the OP knows nearly nothing.

Answer (score 1):

A good website for regex reference and testing is http://rubular.com/

It looks like you need to add a +, which tells the regex to look for one or more of a character.

Try: `\${[a-zA-Z]+}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `*` (*zero or more*) or `+` (*one or more*). So this `[a-zA-Z]` would be `[a-zA-Z]+`, meaning 1 or more letters. The entire regex would look like:

```
\$\{[a-zA-Z]+\}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This answer is correct, was the first answer. Two other answers are essentially copies of this one, yet this one is downvoted?